# Make the original mirrored object invisible

Tags: mirror

[image]

The top object is the original object, and the bottom is that which is mirrored.  Is there a way to make the top object invisible while keeping the mirrored object there?

Answer (score 5):

Don't know how to do this properly, but here is what I came up with:

1. You could create another object that envelops the object you want to hide and use a `boolean` modifier with `difference` set as the operation. Then just hide the enveloping object as shown in the image :-

[image]

2. You could offset the mirrored object's UVs (see image) by (1, 1), then in the shader substract (1, 1) from UV coordinates - the mirrored object will have original UVs and the original object will have negative coordinates. Enable alpha clipping in the material, make transparent everything that has UV coordinates less than 0 and the original object should be invisible. Similar results could achieved by comparing the coordinates of axis the object was mirrored along. The original object would still cast shadows though so beware

[image]

Comment: Using a Boolean modifier to hide a mirrored object!! That's simply brilliant.

Comment: Really clever :). Every solution that gets you there is a 'proper' one.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the *Mirror* then delete the original object, leaving you only with the mirrored one.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)